# How to Ignore element in XPATH

Tags: html, xpath, xpath-1.0

I want to select all `a` tags thats not inside `<div id="not-take-inside">....</div>` element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div><a href="#">TEXT</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">TEXT</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">TEXT</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="not-take-inside">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div><a href="#">TEXT</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">TEXT</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">TEXT</a></div>
        <div>
            <div><a href="#">TEXT</a></div>
            <div><a href="#">TEXT</a></div>
            <div><a href="#">TEXT</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to select all `a` tags thats not inside `<div id="not-take-inside">....</div>` element.

I try XPATH like `//a[parent::*[not(@id='not-take-inside')]]` not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple use `//a[not(ancestor::*[@id='not-take-inside'])]` :)

Answer (score 1):

You only need to select all `a`s which do not have an `ancestor::` attribute node of `@id` with the content `not-take-inside`:

```
//a[not(ancestor::*/@id='not-take-inside')]
```

There is no need for two predicates.

Comment: You also provide a right ans but @ABHIJIT provide ans first